# Line Spacing and Force Lines spacing

Tags: line-spacing

Is there a way to make the line spacing different than that of the forced line spacing?

For instance I would like

```
blah blah blah \\

blah blah blah.
```

to consistently (document wide) produce the equivalent of

```
blah blah blah 

\vspace{4\baselineskip}

blah blah blah.
```

This even though the spacing within each paragraph would remain just 1.

Comment: Are you using ``\\`` to denote a paragraph break?

Comment: your first fragment is a single paragraph, your second one is two.

Comment: it would be simpler just use a blank line not `\\ ` and set `\parskip` to `4\baselineskip`

Comment: You're correct David Carlisle. I'm fixing the question.

Comment: Your first example produces an underfull box because `\\ ` ought not be used to end lines except in special environments such as `tabular` and `array`.

Comment: Why can't you say `blah blah blah \bigskip` and then the blank line and the next bit of text? Or set `\parskip` as suggested if you want it for every paragraph.